# Gear won't change to bottom range if set for top and won't change to top range if set for bottom

Tags: gears

Fit the following, all new drivetrain components to my Pinarelo that has Ultegra shifters:

- Tiagra 11t-34t cassette
- chain
- long cage derailleur
- derailleur hanger

If I set it up such that the top gears work, the bottom 2 gears won't engage. And the other way around: if I set up the derailleur for the bottom gear, the top 2 won't engage.

Scratching my  head as to what might be causing this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to bicycle.se! I'm scratching my head as well regarding what you mean in your question. Could you perhaps [edit] it to provide a bit more explanation? Maybe even a video of the issue?

Comment: Do you mean "won't" instead of "want?"  The question makes a lot more sense if your indexing is off and you can't access the gears at one end of the range when your derailleur is set for the other end.

Comment: It would help if you could state the model numbers for the parts, especially the RD and shifter. One possible incompatibility was given in an answer. If you put a Tiagra cassette, which is 10s, on an 11s drivetrain, that’s another possible incompatibility.

Answer (score 4):

If you have put a brand new Tiagra derailleur on your bike with 10 speed Ultegra then you have installed an incompatible derailleur. Shimano altered the cable pull for the Tiagra 4700 edition and it no longer matches with your original shifters.

This results in insufficient movement of the derailleur and means you can only access the limited range you have identified. The shifting will be imprecise at best even in this limited range.